# Bash elseif statements and prefixes to strings

Tags: bash

I need to make a program that would print out every even number between two variables and if the number is divisible by 7 it would add orange at the end of the digit. The current code doesn't compile. Also how would I go around if the number is divisible by both 7 and 13, for example?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "enter two digits "
read nr1 nr2
eval "t=({$nr1..$nr2})";
for n in "${t[@]}"
do 
    out=$(( $n % 2 ))
if
    [ $out -eq 0 ] 
then  
for o in "${t[@]}"
do 
out2=$(( $o % 7))
elif
[ $out2 -eq 0]
    then
    echo "$o orange, "
for b in "${t[@]}"
do 
    out3=$(( $b % 11))
elif
    [ $out3 -eq 0]
    then
    echo "$b banana, "
for p in "${t[@]}"
do 
    out4=$(( $p % 13))
elif
    [ $out4 -eq 0]
    then
    echo "$o pear, "
else 
echo "$n"
   fi
done
```

Comment: "The current code doesnt compile" um what? You're compiling a bash script?

Comment: meant that it gives me an error

Comment: Start with using a reasonable indentation, which reflects the structure of the script. Post it to https://www.shellcheck.net/ shellcheck, to read about what is wrong, if the message in the shell isn't clear enough.

Comment: If you're just going to create `t` to iterate over, use `for ((n=$nr; n <= $nr2; n++)); do` instead of using `eval` to define an array.

Answer (score 2):

This is how bash and I read the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "enter two digits "
read nr1 nr2
eval "t=({$nr1..$nr2})";
for n in "${t[@]}"
do 
    out=$(( $n % 2 ))
    if
        [ $out -eq 0 ] 
    then  
        for o in "${t[@]}"
        do 
            out2=$(( $o % 7))
        # most probably you missed a `done` here
            elif # elif without if - for doesn't know else/elif
                [ $out2 -eq 0]
            then
                echo "$o orange, "
                for b in "${t[@]}"
                do 
                    out3=$(( $b % 11))
                    elif # again elif without if
                        [ $out3 -eq 0]
                    then
                        echo "$b banana, "
                        for p in "${t[@]}" # no fi so far, so we go deeper
                        do 
                            out4=$(( $p % 13))
                            elif # illegal elif - where is the corresponding if?
                                [ $out4 -eq 0]
                            then
                                echo "$o pear, "
                            else 
                                echo "$n"
                            fi # oh! I had lost my faith
                        done # another closing statement!
```

if/elif/fi have to be on the same indentation level - not as typed characters, but from the logic.

If you start a for in a *then* branch, the for has to be closed with a done, before you may open an elif or end the if with fi.

```
if 
  condition
then
  expression(s)
(elif 
  expression(s))
fi
```

and

```
for (condition)
do
    block 
done
```

can't be cut, only nested. But the inner construct has to be closed before the outer one is closed.

Using a clear indentation helps to see and avoid violations.